# libSVM plotROC using MATLAB giving inconsistent results

Tags: matlab, libsvm

I have a binary classification problem. I'm using libSVM with the plotROC, but the AUC values are bizarre. The accuracy, according to the same function, is 24% (908 out of 3741) and the confusion matrix is
908   0
2833  0

(so one class is always wrong).
But the ROC is extremely nice - AUC = 0.9383 (out of 1). I'm attaching a picture. I'll be happy to provide any more information - and I understand the meaning of the ROC curve - but the AUC is so non-reflective of the accuracy in this case (the point on the ROC curve is really on the left - btw doesn't libSVM choose a point on the ROC that is along the diagonal from 1 to 1 when reporting accuracy?), I can't help thinking maybe something is wrong.

Thank you for your time!

image can be seen at
http://postimg.org/image/mhj40mvnd/

Comment: can you provide a small running example of your code you used to generate these numbers?

Comment: did you use labels -1 and 1 (also during training of the SVM)?